# Image handling in multi-tier ASP.NET MVC 2 app

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I'm looking for some help wrapping my head around a good approach/architecture to handle images in my ASP.NET MVC 2 application.  The application is a client for a middle-tier web service application that encapsulates our domain logic and rules.  The images are stored in a back-end database that is only accessible through the web service.

For the sake of this discussion, we'll use the classic case of a Product which has an associated image. Whenever I display information about the Product, I also show the image.  So, for instance, when viewing a list of Products to an admin for editing, I will show the image and the name of the product as a hyperlink.  when editing, the user can see the existing image and upload a replacement.  I also show the image when users browse lists of Products or look at what items are in their 'shopping cart'.

Needless to say, I have to obtain the image data a lot. (And, yes, caching will be a part of the solution but not part of my question.)

My first task was to create the controller and views used to edit Product data which includes the ability to upload the image.  I followed the approach described in Pro ASP.NET MVC 2 Framework where I set the image element's src to a controller action which returns the image data.  The controller receives a reference to the ProductManagementServiceAgent in its constructor and delegates to the agent which handles the call to the web service.  This works great but, of course, it means two calls back to the service to display the information.

Next I have to display the list of Products, with images, to the admin. In this case it's not a problem because I'm using the same controller with the same action, so I can use the same approach.  Unfortunately, now I'm making 'n+1' calls to the service.

My quandry comes when figuring out how best to handle all of the other use cases where I need to display the image.  Inside the 'shopping cart', for instance.  Should my ShoppingCartController also reference ProductManagementServiceAgent and use the same method to retrieve the product image? This would mean any controller that displays a product image would have to reference the agent, yes?

The first thing that bothers me about this is that I don't like injecting multiple dependencies into a class if I really don't need to and see long parameter lists in constructors as smelly code (tells me the object is trying to do too much).  Plus, the ProductManagementServiceAgent is really intended for the admin UI, so maybe a different agent would be better?  Or a different approach all together?

I have to think that others have already charted this territory, so I appreciate any wisdom to set me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually went with a suggestion not posted to this site so I can't give proper credit.  In a nutshell, we expose additional actions on our controller when an image is required. So, for instance, our ProductController has a ProductImage action method that accepts the product id and returns the image. It seems to satisfy our needs.

Answer (score 0):

Have a dedicated controller for images.

It will have one dependency - the ProductManagementServiceAgent.

Cache it both server side and client side to minimise requests.